# How to translate the text from Whisper to english or any other language

Tags: openai-api, openai-whisper

I have an audio file in a language different than english. I used whisper (https://github.com/openai/whisper) to produce the text from the audio using `model.transcribe()` and it works really great. I'm gonna use it as a captions for my video. However, I'd like to add english captions as well. How can I translate the dictionary of results to the english (or possibly any other language?)